# First Navigation Item jump in Chrome Browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why is the First Menu Item (.chosen) jump in Chrome Browser with refresh? It seems to me that it changes Padding-Right and Padding Padding-Bottom. Please Check the code help me to solve this annoying problem. It is Good in the Firefox

```
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="con_header">
                <h1> SITE NAME</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="chosen"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CONTACTS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>


header {
    background-color: #202628;
    height: 80px;
    color: #e7e7e7;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.con_header{
    width:1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.con_header h1{
    float: left;
    width:500px;

}
.con_header nav{
    float: right;
    width:600px;
}
.con_header::after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}

.con_header ul{
    margin-top:26px;
    padding: 0;
}
.con_header li{
    display: inline;

}
.con_header li a{
    color: #e7e7e7;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 32.5px 8px;
    margin: -4px;
}
.con_header li a:hover{
    color: #e7e7e7;
    background-color: rgb(232,76,61); 
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 32.5px 8px;
    margin: -4px;
}
.chosen{
    color: #e7e7e7;
    background-color: rgb(232,76,61); 
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 32.5px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gives the same output when I try in both chrome and Firefox. The problem, if there is one, should not be with your code. Try using the [css reset tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to reduce browser inconsistencies